# How can I make my python code run faster

Tags: python, performance, loops, timing

I am working on code that loops over multiple netcdf files (large ~28G). The netcdf files have multiple 4D variables[time, east-west, south-north, height] throughout a domain. The goal is to loop over these files and to loop over each location of all of these variables in the domain and pull certain variables to store into a large array. When there is missing or incomplete files I fill the values with 99.99. Right now I am just testing by looping over 2 daily netcdf files but for some reason it is taking forever (~14 hours). I am not sure if there is a way to optimize this code. I don't think that python should take this long for this task but maybe it is a problem with python or my code. Below is my code hopefully it is readable and any suggestions on how to make this faster is greatly appreciated:

```
#Domain to loop over
k_space = np.arange(0,37)
j_space = np.arange(80,170)
i_space = np.arange(200,307)

predictors_wrf=[]
names_wrf=[]

counter = 0
cdate = start_date
while cdate <= end_date:
    if cdate.month not in month_keep:
        cdate+=inc
        continue
    yy = cdate.strftime('%Y')        
    mm = cdate.strftime('%m')
    dd = cdate.strftime('%d')
    filename = wrf_path+'\wrfoutRED_d01_'+yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+'_'+hour_str+'_00_00'
    for i in i_space:
        for j in j_space:
            for k in k_space:
                    if os.path.isfile(filename):
                        f = nc.Dataset(filename,'r')
                        times = f.variables['Times'][1:]
                        num_lines = times.shape[0]
                        if num_lines == 144:
                            u = f.variables['U'][1:,k,j,i]
                            v = f.variables['V'][1:,k,j,i]
                            wspd = np.sqrt(u**2.+v**2.)
                            w = f.variables['W'][1:,k,j,i]
                            p = f.variables['P'][1:,k,j,i]
                            t = f.variables['T'][1:,k,j,i]
                        if num_lines < 144:
                            print "partial files for WRF: "+ filename
                            u = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            v = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            wspd = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            w = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            p = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            t = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                    else:
                        u = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        v = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        wspd = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        w = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        p = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        t = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        counter=counter+1
                    predictors_wrf.append(u)
                    predictors_wrf.append(v)
                    predictors_wrf.append(wspd)
                    predictors_wrf.append(w)
                    predictors_wrf.append(p)
                    predictors_wrf.append(t)
                    u_names = 'u_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    v_names = 'v_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    wspd_names = 'wspd_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    w_names = 'w_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    p_names = 'p_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    t_names = 't_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    names_wrf.append(u_names)
                    names_wrf.append(v_names)
                    names_wrf.append(wspd_names)
                    names_wrf.append(w_names)
                    names_wrf.append(p_names)
                    names_wrf.append(t_names)
    cdate+=inc
```

Comment: you can use multiprocessing to process the files at the same time. arrange the k,j,i spaces for different processes and let each of them do its own task

Comment: What is `nc.Dataset`? Additionally, before you can *improve* speed, you need to know why it is slow. You will need to profile your code and *measure*.

Comment: it is how I read in netcdf files with python I have a statement earlier in the code not shown here: import netCDF4 as nc

Comment: The multi-core suggestion below would help. Also, if you are working in iPython notebook, writing it to a script you run from the command line can MASSIVELY speed things up. 28GB is  huge file. If both files are in that size range and you have 3 loops with conditions, 14 hours on a single core is not out of this world, no matter how ridiculous it seems. R is much slower than Python, and smaller files have taken 8-12 to sort through with less looping..just be as conservative as you can with redundant operations and fire up more cores!

Comment: It seems that you go over the file several times, the {f.variables['Times'][1:]} goes over the file in search of these var. This is done for each one of the loops.  Do this once, not at each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lame first pass to tighten up your `forloop`s. Since you only use the file shape once per file, you can move the handling outside the loop which should reduce the amount of loading of data in interrupting processing. I still don't get what `counter` and `inc` do as they don't seem to be updated in the loop. You definitely want to look into repeated string concatenation performance, or how the performance of your appending to `predictors_wrf` and `names_wrf` looks as starting points

```
k_space = np.arange(0,37)
j_space = np.arange(80,170)
i_space = np.arange(200,307)

predictors_wrf=[]
names_wrf=[]

counter = 0
cdate = start_date
while cdate <= end_date:
    if cdate.month not in month_keep:
        cdate+=inc
        continue
    yy = cdate.strftime('%Y')        
    mm = cdate.strftime('%m')
    dd = cdate.strftime('%d')
    filename = wrf_path+'\wrfoutRED_d01_'+yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+'_'+hour_str+'_00_00'
    file_exists = os.path.isfile(filename)
    if file_exists:
        f = nc.Dataset(filename,'r')
        times = f.variables['Times'][1:]
        num_lines = times.shape[0]
    for i in i_space:
        for j in j_space:
            for k in k_space:
                    if file_exists:    
                        if num_lines == 144:
                            u = f.variables['U'][1:,k,j,i]
                            v = f.variables['V'][1:,k,j,i]
                            wspd = np.sqrt(u**2.+v**2.)
                            w = f.variables['W'][1:,k,j,i]
                            p = f.variables['P'][1:,k,j,i]
                            t = f.variables['T'][1:,k,j,i]
                        if num_lines < 144:
                            print "partial files for WRF: "+ filename
                            u = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            v = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            wspd = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            w = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            p = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                            t = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                    else:
                        u = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        v = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        wspd = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        w = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        p = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        t = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                        counter=counter+1
                    predictors_wrf.append(u)
                    predictors_wrf.append(v)
                    predictors_wrf.append(wspd)
                    predictors_wrf.append(w)
                    predictors_wrf.append(p)
                    predictors_wrf.append(t)
                    u_names = 'u_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    v_names = 'v_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    wspd_names = 'wspd_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    w_names = 'w_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    p_names = 'p_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    t_names = 't_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                    names_wrf.append(u_names)
                    names_wrf.append(v_names)
                    names_wrf.append(wspd_names)
                    names_wrf.append(w_names)
                    names_wrf.append(p_names)
                    names_wrf.append(t_names)
    cdate+=inc
```

Answer (score 2):

For your questions, I think [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) will help a lot.  I went through your codes and have some pieces of advice here.

1. Not using start time, but the filenames as the iterators in your codes.

   Wrap a function to find out all the file names based on time and return a list     of all filenames.

   ```
   def fileNames(start_date, end_date):
       # Find all filenames.
       cdate = start_date
       fileNameList = [] 
       while cdate <= end_date:
           if cdate.month not in month_keep:
               cdate+=inc
               continue
           yy = cdate.strftime('%Y')        
           mm = cdate.strftime('%m')
           dd = cdate.strftime('%d')
           filename = wrf_path+'\wrfoutRED_d01_'+yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+'_'+hour_str+'_00_00'
           fileNameList.append(filename)
           cdate+=inc

       return fileNameList
   ```
2. Wrap your codes that pull your data and fill with 99.99, the input for the function is the file name.

   ```
   def dataExtraction(filename):
       file_exists = os.path.isfile(filename)
       if file_exists:
          f = nc.Dataset(filename,'r')
          times = f.variables['Times'][1:]
          num_lines = times.shape[0]
       for i in i_space:
           for j in j_space:
               for k in k_space:
                   if file_exists:    
                       if num_lines == 144:
                           u = f.variables['U'][1:,k,j,i]
                           v = f.variables['V'][1:,k,j,i]
                           wspd = np.sqrt(u**2.+v**2.)
                           w = f.variables['W'][1:,k,j,i]
                           p = f.variables['P'][1:,k,j,i]
                           t = f.variables['T'][1:,k,j,i]
                       if num_lines < 144:
                           print "partial files for WRF: "+ filename
                           u = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           v = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           wspd = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           w = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           p = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           t = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                       else:
                           u = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           v = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           wspd = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           w = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           p = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           t = np.ones((144,))*99.99
                           counter=counter+1
                       predictors_wrf.append(u)
                       predictors_wrf.append(v)
                       predictors_wrf.append(wspd)
                       predictors_wrf.append(w)
                       predictors_wrf.append(p)
                       predictors_wrf.append(t)
                       u_names = 'u_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                       v_names = 'v_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                       wspd_names = 'wspd_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                       w_names = 'w_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                       p_names = 'p_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                       t_names = 't_'+str(k)+'_'+str(j)+'_'+str(i)
                       names_wrf.append(u_names)
                       names_wrf.append(v_names)
                       names_wrf.append(wspd_names)
                       names_wrf.append(w_names)
                       names_wrf.append(p_names)
                       names_wrf.append(t_names)


       return zip(predictors_wrf, names_wrf)
   ```
3. Using multiprocessing to do your work.  Generally, all the computers have more than 1 CPU cores.  Multiprocessing will help increase the speed when there  are massive CPU calculations. To my previous experience, multiprocessing will reduce up to 2/3 time consumed for huge datasets.

   Updates: After testing my codes an files again on Feb. 25, 2017, I found that using 8 cores for a huge dataset saved me 90% of collapsed time.

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
         from multiprocessing import Pool  # This should be in the beginning statements.
         start_date = '01-01-2017'
         end_date = '01-15-2017'
         fileNames = fileNames(start_date, end_date)
         p = Pool(4) # the cores numbers you want to use.
         results = p.map(dataExtraction, fileNames)
         p.close()
         p.join()
   ```
4. Finally, be careful about the data structures here as it is pretty complicated.  Hope this helps.  Please leave comments if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have very many suggestions, but a couple of things to note.

**Don't open that file so many times**

First, you define this `filename` variable and then inside this loop (deep inside: three for-loops deep), you are checking if the file exists and presumably opening it there (I don't know what `nc.Dataset` does, but I'm guessing it must open the file and read it):

```
filename = wrf_path+'\wrfoutRED_d01_'+yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+'_'+hour_str+'_00_00'
    for i in i_space:
        for j in j_space:
            for k in k_space:
                    if os.path.isfile(filename):
                        f = nc.Dataset(filename,'r')
```

This is going to be pretty inefficient. You can certainly open it once if the file doesn't change before all of your loops.

**Try to Use Fewer for-loops**

All of these nested for-loops are compounding the number of operations you need to perform. General suggestion: try to use numpy operations instead.

**Use CProfile**

If you want to know why your programs are taking a long time, one of the best ways to find out is to profile them.